# ASP.NET Web API - SQL - Retrieving Information

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api

I am having some issues with retrieving information from sql database using ASP.net Web API.

I have tried to use forms, which worked great (using gridview) but when I try to do it using a separate class dedicated to store my specific table information I get this error:

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

This is the code:

```
  public ActionResult Details()
    {
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeContext"].ConnectionString;
        using (var myConn = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblEmployee", myConn);
            myConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                int i = 0;
                employeeList[i].PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["PersonID"]);
                employeeList[i].Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                employeeList[i].Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                employeeList[i].City = rdr["City"].ToString();
                employeeList[i].DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["DepartmentID"]);
                i++;
            }
            return View(employeeList);
        }
    }
```

This is the Employee class:

```
[Table("tblEmployee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
```

}
}

I get this error on any of the retrieving information lines.

The table has 5 columns: PersonID(int PK), Name(nvarchar), Gender(nvarchar), City(nvarchar), DepartmentID(int).

I checked many times the columns names to make sure I didn't got those wrong and I double checked the connection string which is also fine (the same code works with gridview using forms API).

Hope someone can help me with this. I didn't find any specific information on that and I guess it's should be easy and I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to populate a `List<>` object by using an index.  To populate a `List<>` you need to use `.Add()`.  You need to change your code from this:

```
int i = 0;
employeeList[i].PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["PersonID"]);
employeeList[i].Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
employeeList[i].Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
employeeList[i].City = rdr["City"].ToString();
employeeList[i].DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["DepartmentID"]);
i++;
```

To this:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();

emp.PersonID     = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["PersonID"]);
emp.Name         = rdr["Name"].ToString();
emp.Gender       = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
emp.City         = rdr["City"].ToString();
emp.DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["DepartmentID"]);

employeeList.Add(emp);
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding a new item to a `list`, you should use `.Add()`.  Here's one option:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    employeeList.Add(new Employee {
        PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["PersonID"]),
        Name = rdr["Name"].ToString(),
        Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString(),
        City = rdr["City"].ToString(),
        DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["DepartmentID"])
    });
}
```

You could then access individual items in the list with their `index` or by using `foreach`.